# Matlab readtable - not giving last column

Tags: excel, matlab

The `readtable` function in Matlab for reading an MS-Excel spreadsheet is not giving me the last column. Why?

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
function assetslist = loadAssets()
      xlFileDetails = 'mypath';
      xlsheet = 'mysheet';

      result = readtable(xlFileDetails,'Sheet',xlsheet,...
                        'ReadRowNames',true,'ReadVariableNames',true);
      result(:,end)=[]; % append empty list in case no data
      assetslist = result;
    end
```

Sample data from my excel file is:

Num  Ticker       IQIndex  IBIndex UseIB IbType  IbCur   IbXch
   1    SPX Index    SPX.XO              0
   2    CCMP Index   COMPX.X             0
   3    RTY Index    RUT.X    RUT        1  IND     USD     RUSSEL

But the result of the call gives me data with the last column missing.

Num  Ticker       IQIndex  IBIndex UseIB IbType  IbCur
   1    SPX Index    SPX.XO              0
   2    CCMP Index   COMPX.X             0
   3    RTY Index    RUT.X    RUT        1  IND     USD

(My real data has 11 columns and only 10 are retrieved...)

I'm using Matlab R2017b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result(:,end)=[];
```

deletes the last column.

Change it to

```
result(:,end+1)=[];
```